# Requirements to be a Sponsor for a Catholic Baptism

Tags: catholicism, baptism

A family member of mine honored me by asking to be his son's god parent in baptism. However, I have not yet completed all the required sacraments under Code of Canon Law. I am not yet confirmed, due to a busy school and work schedule. However, I am a Catholic who has not left the church. In this case, am I still able to be a sponsor (or witness) in this child's baptism?

An idea that has been told to me by some friends and family is that I consider an "fast" confirmation so I may be a godparent, but I feel that this is not something to take lightly.

Thank you for your helping.

Comment: It appears not - this seems to be a duplicate; I'll link to the duplicate but I'll request this be closed. You can refer to the original.

Comment: You may be able to get a dispensation from the bishop; ask your priest.